# Is it possible to write a contract where exchange happens in an offline (no Internet) LAN environment

Tags: contract-development

Is it possible to create a contract to broke an exchange/transaction between two parties where the two parties may or may not be connected to the internet when the transaction occurs, and they may not reconnect to the Internet after the transaction. How will the network verify such transaction if such transaction could be done?

For example:

Suppose Alice and Bob makes a contract where they could at a future time they could make some transaction at a later time (They are not in an offline environment when the contract is broke). Neither Alice and Bob are obligated to make a transaction, but if Alice and Bob could talk to each other in a p2p manner without Internet (perhaps HTTP in a LAN for instance), they should be able to perform such transaction. Is it possible for Alice and Bob to make such transaction if neither of them has access to the Internet and the main Ethereum network? What strategy do I have to make this possible if I assume neither Bob nor Alice has access to the Internet, **and** neither of them will reconnect to the Internet/could access the Ethereum network after the contract has been broke.

If such transaction isn't possible (my intuition tells me that it isn't), is it possible in a case, where either Alice or Bob connects to the Internet perhaps, after the transaction take place. If only Alice connects to the Ethereum network, how does the network verify that what Alice said was true, that Bob did indeed initiate the transaction with Alice, even though Bob will probably never connect to the Ethereum network.

Comment: Are you wanting this contract / transaction to live on the main ethereum network?

Comment: Yes, I want the contract to be on the mainnet. Mostly asking if the transaction which may/may not occur after could be on the mainnet if neither of the clients could connect to the main ethereum network.

Comment: So, you're asking if Alice and Bob can make a transaction on the Ethereum network without the ability to connect to the Ethereum network?

Comment: Well, I'm assuming when the contract was broke, they both have access to the Ethereum network. I'm just asking if it's possible to have transactions after the fact where neither of them are on the Ethereum network even though the contract still exists between Alice and Bob, and they have p2p connectivity.

Comment: Do Alice and/or Bob need to trigger anything for the transactions to take place? Or could the contract be programmed perform transactions on Alice and Bob's behalf at a future date?

Comment: This contract requires user intervention to take place at some future date. My intuition tells me that this isn't possible to do, is it even possible if either Bob/Alice connects to the Internet (1/2 days perhaps) after the transaction has occurred, but not during the transaction.

Answer (score 2):

Ok from your further clarification it sounds like something like the http://raiden.network/ would be a potential solution for your problem.

You want a contract to be broadcast to the network, but you want the users to transact over a local network. To have the contract finalised on the Ethereum network you can have your local raiden network broadcast the result to the mainnet.